# Could a Large Marine Organism Develop an EMP Capable of Disabling Watercraft?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, genetic-engineering

Let's say a genetically engineered organism (as large as a whale), capable of swimming and breathing underwater, have an EMP field as a form of defense against man-made watercraft like warships and submarines? Is this realistically plausible? How would it work if it did?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "EMP field." Might the creature instead use electronic interference or jamming or simply be very hard to detect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many modern man-made military devices are very hardened against EMPs so even man powered EMP devices are largely impractical. Nature, especially when it comes to electronics or really anything we're "good at"is much less efficient. electric eels, for example, are only 14% efficient when converting sugar into electricity. 
However, with boats, and especially subs, you don't need to fry their electronics to render them useless. Subs rely heavily on sonar for navigation so if you were to have a whale to emitted "sonar" at the same frequency as the subs you could likely "blind" them forcing them to surface or risk crashing.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Supamee! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

While something like a giant [electric ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_ray) could theoretically produce enough charge to act as a [NNEMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse#Non-nuclear_electromagnetic_pulse_(NNEMP)) military vessels that are hardened to withstand the EMP from the close detonation of even enhanced EMP nuclear weapons aren't going to be affected by anything that small and localised. Civilian shipping might need to look out but warships are going to be in more damage from a ramming attack.

Comment: i have a mental image of an angry blue whale breaching  up onto the deck of a destroyer and capsizing it... something like that? not sure the weight difference would be enough but its funny to think about.

Comment: @BladeWraith Something like that yeah.